# Qmail: Send all outgoing mails to local file

Tags: qmail

When I have to test an email-sending web application on a server, how could I achive that every mails which should get delivered non-local (be sent to some remote smtp) gets stored in a local file (or mailbox) instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the qmail-tap feature, which is documented below:

> If you want to keep a copy of incoming and outgoing mail of an account
>   in a qmail server, you can use the qmail-tap feature.
>
> Qmail provides the ability to make a copy of each email that flows
>   through the system. Qmail tap feature has the following
>   functionalities:
>
> - Specify which email addresses tap using a regex style control file. With the regex function, you can specify full domains or individual
>     email addresses.
> - Specify which email address to send the tapped email address.
>
> Qmail does not need to be restarted to change the above. Just update the taps control file.
>
> The taps file is not included in the basic, default toaster install.
>   You can configure it as follows:
>
> `[root@qmail ~]# touch /var/qmail/control/taps`
>
> `[root@qmail ~]# vi /var/qmail/control/taps`
>
> Insert the tap information and save
>
> **Examples:**
>
> a) To tap a whole domain add a line like:
>
> `.*@domain.com:bcc@example.com`
>
> 'bcc@example.com' gets a copy of all incoming and outgoing mail for
>   the domain, 'domain.com'
>
> b) To tap an individual email address add a line like:
>
> `user@domain.com:other@example.com`
>
> `'other@domain.com'` gets a copy of all incoming and outgoing mail for
>   `'user@domain.com'`